# Default data to be created into database upon table creation

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I am using Sequelize in my NestJS project for the first time. When Sequelize connects to the database it automatically creates the tables and their schemas. I would also like for it to automatically import some default data into the database. For example DimSetting would have a bunch of default settings imported.

Comment: There is something called seeds.with seeds you can insert some default data to the database.https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#running-seeds

Comment: I would've thought you would be able to create a JSON object in your source that can be auto imported on init (when the tables are created).

Comment: Sequlizer seeds are javascript functions.so you could write any codes there to import ,parse json and insert to tables.But i don't think their is a inbuilt functions to do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning NestJS and Sequelize, so this answer may or not be a good approach, but I wanted to create a default entry into a `Users` table when the table is first created.

It seemed like a good place to do this is in my `UsersService`, so I did the following:

`user.model.ts:`

```js
import { Column, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
export class User extends Model {
    @Column
    username: string;

    // ... other properties
}
```

`users.service.ts`:

```js
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService implements OnModuleInit {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(User)
        private readonly userModel: typeof User,
    ) {}

    async onModuleInit() {
        await this.createDefaultUser();
    }

    async createDefaultUser() {
        // if the table isn't empty return
        if ((await this.userModel.count()) > 0) return;

        await User.create({ username: 'fred' });
    }
}
```